# EvoPdf Html to Pdf Converter taking longer during conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, html-to-pdf, evopdf

I'm using EvoPdf to convert html using method, GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(). It is taking between 13 to 16 seconds on an app deployed on IIS and at times it takes as low as 2 to 4 seconds for the same activity. I though it might be the html causing the issue so I even replaced with two lines within the html body but it still took exactly that long. I applied some logs and noticed that below event was actually the culprit, where it took the long time, Dont know what caused it to take that long:

```
pdfConverter.NavigationCompletedEvent += NavigationCompleted;
```

I used ProcMon for the first time to figure out the issue but I'm not quite good at it. I found that evoInternal.dat is the file which almost took 7 seconds (as per Process Tree). When I applied filter against process name 'evo', the Path column showed various system files with in Windows\SysWOW64, with Results column showed 'NAME NOT FOUND', 'FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS' besides 'SUCCESS'. So I don't know how to troubleshoot and find the area where its taking 16 seconds around.

Can anyone guide me the way I should look further into the ProcMon to figure out the issue or some one experiencing the same slowness issue and got over it.